# PHP Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements - CSV not parsing properly?

Tags: php, csv, array-combine

For the following CSV file (3MB):
[ACDF_cut.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/du578v7pumy98u9/ACDF_cut.csv?dl=0)

And for the following code:

```
<?php

$file = fopen("ACDF_cut.csv","r");
$file2 = fopen("ACDF_cut_rounded.csv","w");


    /* Map Rows and Loop Through Them */
    $rows   = array_map('str_getcsv', file('ACDF_cut.csv'));
    $header = array_shift($rows);
    $csv    = array();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }



foreach ($csv as &$product){//Use of & as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/40913938/9095603
    $product['LQ Price'] = number_format($product['LQ Price'],2); 
    $product['AvailableQty'] = number_format($product['AvailableQty']); 
    $product['Net Weight'] = number_format($product['Net Weight'],2); 
}


foreach ($csv as $product) {
  fputcsv($file2, $product);
}


 fclose($file);
 fclose($file2);
```

I get

> [03-Jan-2020 17:00:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_combine(): Both
>   parameters should have an equal number of elements in
>   /home/kalugi/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/round_ACDF_cut.php
>   on line 20

I can't see how it's possible that `$header` and `$row` don't have an equal number of elements.

But indeed on checking I see that:

```
echo count($header) = 13
echo count($rows) = 8552
```

Yet they derive from the same non-ragged CSV file where the number of headers matches the number of fields on each row.  To make matters more confusing, I've operated on this same file before and never had issues with unequal header and row counts.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `file()` doesn't recognize the newlines in the file, so it put everything in one line. What is `count($rows)`?

Comment: You have a newline on line 8446 of your csv in the Description1 field  that's breaking your import. I'm guessing that may not be the only one.

Comment: Though, why are you using the file function and str_getcsv, when you can just use fgetcsv on `$file`?

Comment: @Barmar `$rows` count = 8552 (`$header` count = 13)

Comment: When I scroll down in the file, row 1086 seems to be malformed.

Comment: Also line 1310, and probably others. Fix the file.

Comment: `count($rows)` is irrelevant, what matters is `count($row)` on every row.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I think you are onto something - `count($row)` is variable, sometimes it's 2, 11, 12, etc.